# How do I turn on Survival Mode?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The release notes for the latest version of Fallout Shelter include the following item:

- Faced all the challenges the "normal" Vault simulation can provide? Introducing Survival Mode!  More danger, More glory.  Make Vault-Tec proud.

I have gone through every menu item in the game and started a new vault, but I cannot figure out how to turn on Survival Mode.  How is it turned on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to start a new vault. It has a box to check if you want to play survival mode.

[image: Very Difficult To Find Option]

Comment: Good night!  That is practically invisible.

Comment: Gawd, that's... just terrible.  It blends into the background.